# Caret position in textarea and surrounding characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I need is this. I need a function that gets position of cursor in textarea and check if surrounding characters are "<" and ">" (without ""). I have a function that gets caret position

```
  function getCaret(el) { 
  if (el.selectionStart) { 
    return el.selectionStart; 
  } else if (document.selection) { 
    el.focus(); 

    var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
    if (r == null) { 
      return 0; 
    } 

    var re = el.createTextRange(), 
        rc = re.duplicate(); 
    re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark()); 
    rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re); 

    return rc.text.length; 
  }  
  return 0; 
  }
```

So this is example:

```
<textarea>
<paragraph>Text goes here.</paragraph>
<picture>Picture</picture>*(* is caret)
</textarea>

function xyz(){
var i=getCaret(textarea);
var previous_character=textarea.value(i-1);
var next_character=textarea.value(i+1);
    if(previous_character==some_character and next_character==some_character){
    do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the the characters using String objects charAt function (character at)

```
var previous_character=textarea.value.charAt(i-1);
var next_character=textarea.value.charAt(i);  // i will give you the next
```